# Curl to node.js 's server. but not return anything. How can I make the server.js return 200 json?

Tags: php, node.js, curl, express, redis

I am using a notification system on node.js and i am trying to use curl in php and push notification to it.

However, each time I use curl in terminal or php, it not returns anything but the notification, indeed, is pushed.

How can I make this code return 200 instead of return nothing and keep curl running until timeout?

```
/* CONFIGURATION */

/* Web Server Config */
var _postpath = '/send';
var _listenport = 8888;
var _listenaddr = '0.0.0.0';  //use '0.0.0.0' to listen on all interfaces

/* Slave (sub) Redis Server Config */
var _channelfilter = '*';
var _sub_db_addr = '127.0.0.1';
var _sub_db_passwd_protected = true;
var _sub_db_passwd = 'secret';
var _sub_db_port = 6379;  //default redis port is 6379

/* Master (pub) Redis Server Config */
var _pub_db_addr = '127.0.0.1';
var _pub_db_passwd_protected = true;
var _pub_db_passwd = 'secret';
var _pub_db_port = 6379;  //default redis port is 6379

/* SocketIO Config */
var _loglevel = 1;

/* simple-pub-sub Config */
var _secretkey = "secret";


/* SERVER CODE -- DO NOT MODIFY */
redis = require('redis');
express = require('express');
socketio = require('socket.io');
fs = require("fs"),
pub = redis.createClient(_pub_db_port, _pub_db_addr); if (_pub_db_passwd_protected) {  }

sub = redis.createClient(_sub_db_port, _sub_db_addr); if (_sub_db_passwd_protected) { }
sub.on("pmessage", function(pattern, channel, json) { io.sockets.volatile.emit(channel, JSON.parse(json)); });
sub.psubscribe('*');

app = express.createServer(express.static(__dirname + '/public'),express.bodyParser());
app.listen(_listenport, _listenaddr);
app.post(_postpath, function(req, res){
  if(req.body.secretkey==_secretkey){
    delete req.body.secretkey; pub.publish(req.body.channel, JSON.stringify(req.body))
  }
});

io = socketio.listen(app);
io.configure(function () { io.set('log level', _loglevel) });
```

Thank you!

Comment: `res.writeHead(200); res.end();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send on the post a 200 code

```
app.post(_postpath, function(req, res){
  if(req.body.secretkey==_secretkey){
    delete req.body.secretkey; pub.publish(req.body.channel, JSON.stringify(req.body));
    res.send(200);
  }
});
```